# render ActiveRecord response in from Controller to View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I'm new to Rails. I'm using Rails 3.2.13. I'll try to keep my question succinct:

In my controller, I want to get the last 10 entries from the Observation table. I have:

```
def index
   @times = Observation.select(:load_time).last(10)
end
```

In that view, I attempt to render the 10 entries in `@times` like this:

```
<% @times.each do |time| %>
<p>time: <%= time %></p>
<% end %>
```

A response I get in my web page looks like this:

```
time: #<Observation:0x007fe22bf2a138>
```

I'm wondering how to get the actual time variable as a float rather than (what looks like) a memory address. It appears that the last 10 entries are correctly making it to the controller which is good.

There is no logic in my Observation < ActiveRecord::Base class because the migration is responsible for defining the schema. Here's what my db/migrate/create_observations.rb looks like:

```
class CreateObservations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :observations do |t|
        t.float :load_time
        t.timestamps        
    end
```

Thanks in advance for any help - it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to access the variable inside the object

```
<%= time.your_field %>
```

in your case:

```
<%= time.load_time %>
```

Comment: `Observation#load_time` is a float column, not a date.

Answer (score 1):

In your view, `<%= time =>` translates to `_buf << time.to_s` (where `_buf` is ERb's internal output buffer). An easy workaround to this is to define `Observation#to_s`, like so:

```rb
class Observation < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    load_time.to_s
  end
end
```

Be aware that a `Observation.select(:id).map(&:to_s)` now would cause an `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError` error (since `to_s` requires this column to be present).

In general, I'd adwise to explicitly fetch the result you need, i.e. in your case:

```
<% @times.each do |time| %>
  <p>time: <%= time.load_time %></p>
<% end %>
```